# When running the cucumber tests they get skipped why?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am quite new to both  Cucumber testing and Spring boot.
I added cucumber-java and cucumber-junit in my pom.xml file
`
CucumberIntergration.test

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/", plugin = 
{"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},dryRun = true,glue = 
{"com.villvay.gudppl.ws"})
```

This is the Version.feature file the feature file for Api Version verification.

```
Feature: the version can be retrieved
 Scenario: client makes call to GET /version
 Given the client makes the api call for verification
 When  the client retrieve the response
 Then  the client verify the response
```

This is a fraction of VersionStepDefinitions.java file where i locates my tests.

```
  @Given("^the client makes the api call for verification")
  public void wants(){
    LOG.info("Client wants to verify the version");
    someUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Gudppl-WS/services/api/summary";
    httpPost = new HttpPost(someUrl);
  }

  @When("^the client retrieve the response")
  public void call() throws IOException {
     getResult = httpsClient.execute(httpPost);
  }

  @Then("^the client verify the response")
  public void test() {
     Assert.assertNotNull(getResult);
     Assert.assertEquals(200, getResult);
  }
}
```

But when i run the tests these tests get skipped.

[Test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLruX.png)

Can any one help?

Comment: I can't get you

Comment: I tried what you said and ended up with the same result

Comment: What is the package information on the stepdef class? Is it inside the package structure mentioned in glue? Also u have set dryrun to true, to run the code switch it to false or delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Turn `dryRun=false`
Or just don't specify that it's true.

It's used to verify whether the cucumber is able to recognise all your steps.
One thing you can add to make sure your logs are readable is that add `monochrome=true`